# Square root of Diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I cannot find an answer to if it is generally possible to take the square root of a diagonal matrix $A$ by taking the square root of each individual component along the main diagonal, e.g. for a 2-by-2 matrix
$$
        \sqrt{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{a_1} & 0 \\
        0 & \sqrt{a_2} \\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is this OK to do provided that it is a (square) diagonal matrix?

Comment: It is sufficient to observe that $\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{a_1} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{a_2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{a_1} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{a_2}\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & 0 \\ 0 & a_2\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you consider matrices with entries in a field $\mathbb{F}$. If square roots $\sqrt{a_i}$ **exist** in $\mathbb{F}$, then it is ok. However, a diagonal matrix $A$ may have a square root even if the $a_i$ do not square roots in $\mathbb{F}$. An example for $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ is
$$
        A = \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$
In fact, a square root of $A$ is given by
$$
        B = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does field $\mathbb{F}$ imply any special properties, or is it an arbitrary field?

Comment: The field is arbitrary. But the properties of $\mathbb{F}$ determine whether **every** (diagonal) matrix $A$ has a square root, and whether there exist square roots in diagonal form. For example, the matrix $A$ in my answer has a square root, but no diagonal square root. For $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$ it has a diagonal square root.