# Is it possible to "split" a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I saw an example where they have:
$\|Z\|_{2,D}^{2}= Z^TDZ$

Given D, a diagonal matrix, they rewrite the former expression as follows:

$\|Z\|_{2,D}^{2}= Z^TDZ\\
=Z^TD^{1/2}D^{1/2}Z\\
=Z^T{(D^{1/2})}^TD^{1/2}Z\\
={(D^{1/2}Z)}^TD^{1/2}Z\\
=\mu^{T}\mu$

I'm struggling to understand why the diagonal matrix D can be express as:
$D=D^{1/2}D^{1/2}$

Is it right to "split" D in that way, if so why is it right?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Your notation is not enough to make the meaning of "split a diagonal matrix" clear to Readers.  It seems to mix scalar and matrix quantities.   Probably adding words to explain the intent will help.

Comment: Check that it works for a small diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Stuck it definitely makes sense, I just checked with a 2x2 matrix and it works. It was conspicuous and I didn't see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here, $D^{1/2}$ is defined to be a matrix such that:

$$
D = D^{1/2} D^{1/2}
$$

The question of whether $D^{1/2}$ always exists or is unique is more difficult to answer. For an example, see: [Square root of Diagonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965025/square-root-of-diagonal-matrix)

Comment: Indeed one can find the obvious square root when $D$ is nonnegative, but it isn't so clear what would be a good choice if the entries of $D$ are otherwise.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah, I think some context would help out here. Most likely the author had something specific in mind.